# Error: Files glob patterns specified did not match any files

Tags: javascript, node.js

[This is my github](https://github.com/FAOfao931013/learnRedux)

When I npm run dev

This error will happen,but it doesn't influence my project

Although everything is ok，I want to solve this error

fuhaodeMacBook-Pro:learnRedux fuhao$ npm run dev

> learnRedux@1.0.0 dev /Users/fuhao/Workspace/fuhao/learnRedux
>   node server.js

Listening at http://localhost:8010

webpack building...

> Error: Files glob patterns specified did not match any files

webpack built 955aef52aa91434f6ef1 in 2670ms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case I got same error:

It was caused because there were no `scss` or `css` files in the `/src` folder and my webpack config contains such settings for `stylelint` loader:

```
new StyleLintPlugin({
  configFile: './stylelint.json',
  context: "./src",
  files: "**/*.scss"
})
```

I didn't find any solution for that error as it didn't affect my build at all.